Apache camel salesforce connector configuration debugging
I am trying to deploy the camel-salesforce-source connector.
I have downloaded the camel-salesforce-source-kafka-connector-4.4.2-package.tar.gz tar file from maven, extracted it to a dir and added the dir in the plugins path of connect-distributed.
I have also extracted the camel-salesforce-kafka-connector-0.9.0-package.tar.gz and added it to the plugins.
The list of connectors shows all camel and SF connectors as expected
"org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSinkConnector"
"org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSinkConnector"
"org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.salesforce.CamelSalesforceSinkConnector"
"org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnector"
"org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnector"
"org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.salesforce.CamelSalesforceSourceConnector"
"org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.salesforcesource.CamelSalesforcesourceSourceConnector"

When I try to start the connector I get an error -
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/kafkaconnector/CamelSourceConnectorConfig

My config for connector looks like
{
    "name": "SF-poll",
    "config": {
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connector.class": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.salesforce.CamelSalesforceSourceConnector",
        "camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.query": "SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone FROM Contact",
        "camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.topicName": "sf-contact",
        "camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.loginUrl": "https://org--qa.sandbox.lightning.force.com/",
        "camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.clientId": "***",
        "camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.clientSecret": "***",
        "camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.userName": "***",
        "camel.kamelet.salesforce-source.password": "***"
    }
}

And my connect-distributed.properties -
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094

group.id=connect-cluster

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
consumer.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
consumer.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1

status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1

offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/home/ubuntu/Downloads/kafka_2.12-3.5.2/libs,/home/ubuntu/Downloads/kafka_2.12-3.5.2/camel-salesforce-source-kafka-connector

What is missing here?

The errors were due to duplicate dependencies. I resolved it by creating an Uber jar file for the connector. Here are the steps -

Download/Clone the camel connector repo.
https://github.com/apache/camel-kafka-connector

Navigate to the connector directory which you want to build
e.g. camel-kafka-connector-main/connectors/camel-salesforce-source-kafka-connector

Create a fat/uber jar by changing the pom.xml directed below
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/tooling/maven/camel-maven-plugin/src/main/docs/camel-maven-plugin.adoc#camelprepare-fatjar


Include this plugin in the pom.xml for the connector
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-fatjar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

For example to use this with the maven-assembly-plugin you can do as below. Remember to specify the class name of your main class where it says com.foo.NameOfMainClass:
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-fatjar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.foo.NameOfMainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

Or with the maven-shade plugin in my case
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <executions>
         <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-fatjar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.salesforcesource.CamelSalesforcesourceSourceConnector</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
       </plugin>


Copy the Uber/fat jar from the target folder to your plugin directory for the Kafka connector.

Thanks.
